# Spring Boot: How to resolve Content-Type when incorrectly received from server

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, networking, mime-types

I have the following class in Java. I'm expecting it to issue a GET request to the url, get back a JSON payload, and transform that payload to `List<LocationData>`.

```
package ...
import ...

@Repository
public class ProxiedLocationRepo {

    public List<LocationData> findAll() throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String url = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString("https://my-host/path")
                .queryParams("some", "queryParams")
                .toUriString();

        ResponseEntity<List<LocationData>> res = restTemplate.exchange(
                                                     url,
                                                     HttpMethod.GET,
                                                     null,
                                                     new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<LocationData>>(){});

        if (res.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.ACCEPTED) {
            return res.getBody();
        } else {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(res.getStatusCode(), "Did not receive a 200 response from Server.");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting back this error:

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "charset=UTF-8": does not contain '/'
```

Which is expected, because if I do the same request from curl, and check the headers I get this (notice Content-Type line):

```
$ curl -sfi 'https://my-host/path?some=queryParams'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2019 13:58:58 GMT
Content-Type: charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1821
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

... # perfectly formatted JSON payload here
```

I know that the Content-Type returned from this server is going to be `application/json`, but it is not providing it to me.

Is there anyway to inform `RestTemplate#exchange` of what the Content-Type of the response will be? If not, is there any other methodology I could use to resolve this issue besides getting the owners of the server to set the Content-Type correctly?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried adding the "Accept" header but got the same results:

```
$ curl -sfi 'https://my-host/path?some=queryParams' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json'
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a correct [Content-Type request header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326397/curl-get-request-with-json-parameter) in curl? See the usage of the -H argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried this and the request actually fails if I set the content type like `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: I tried `-H 'Accept: application/json'` as well. The request worked for this, but the Content-Type returned was still just "charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Fix the server?

Comment: " is there any other methodology I could use to resolve this issue besides getting the owners of the server to set the Content-Type correctly?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there's any way to fix this while leveraging the Spring framework. Even if you were to create a custom `JsonbHttpMessageConverter` that accepts a MIME type of ANY, Spring would still fail to parse the incorrect Content-Type received from the request (because it can't find `"/"` in the Content-Type string).

So the resolution here was to do use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` to do the networking instead, and then use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` to map from the JSON to a POJO.

It works, but at the cost of no longer being able to leverage any of Spring's HTTP handling, which is likely much much more robust than anything I can implement alone.