# PHP: How to send cURL request using GET?

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL for an API call, below is my code:

```
$data = array(
            'r'                          =>  'create',
            '_object'                    =>  'Question',
            '_api_key'                   =>  '........',
            '_user_id'                   =>  $creator_id,
            '_subtype_id'                =>  $type_id,
            '_subtopic_id'               =>  $subtopic_id,
            '_title'                     =>  $title,
            '_description'               =>  $description,             
            '_encoded_xml'               =>  $main_xml
        );
     
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://urlhere/v1/resources/objects");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);    
        curl_close ($ch);
        print_r($server_output);
```

I want these parameters to be sent as `GET` request instead of `POST`, how can I do that pls advise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curl GET request with json parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326397/curl-get-request-with-json-parameter)

Comment: that is  based on commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is for the body (payload) of a `POST` request. For `GET` requests, the payload is part of the URL.

You just need to construct the URL with the arguments you need to send (if any), and remove the other options to cURL.

```
$data = array(
            'r'             =>  'create',
            '_object'       =>  'Question',
            '_api_key'      =>  '........',
            '_user_id'      =>  $creator_id,
            '_subtype_id'   =>  $type_id,
            '_subtopic_id'  =>  $subtopic_id,
            '_title'        =>  $title,
            '_description'  =>  $description,             
            '_encoded_xml'  =>  $main_xml
        );


        $send_data = http_build_query($data);
     
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://urlhere/v1/resources/objects?" . $send_data);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
        
        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);    
        curl_close ($ch);
        print_r($server_output);
```

Comment: i am sending $data array to the server as get request so should i add ?iitem= itemval  ,  like this in  url ?

Comment: Ah yes... add something like this... `$send_data = http_build_query($data);` adding it to your URL, I've updated the code in the answer.