# Php/curl/chrome browser send json data in a get request?

Tags: php, json, http, curl

i have a distant api service which ask for all our requests:

Accept: application/json

clientname: {mynamevalue}

clientsecret: {mysecretvalue}

The first command available is name 'get_contacts'

The http request is `GET https://www.example.com/api/contacts`

For what i understand you cant send a body with the parameters `$clientname` and `$clientsecret`.

You can only do that:

```
https://www.example.com/api/contacts/?clientname=aaaaaa&clientsecret=bbbbb
```

Am i right?

Or is it possible to send a json structure in a get request?
How to do with php?

Thanks all
Good evening

I tried

```
https://www.example.com/api/contacts/?clientname=aaaaaa&clientsecret=bbbbb
```

not working
and :

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/api/contacts/?clientname='.urlencode($login).'&     clientsecret='.urlencode($password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You can send any format you want in a GET request.

Comment: You're correct, you can't send a body in a `GET` request. Try getting rid of the spaces between `&` and `clientsecret`.

Comment: @user3783243 But GET doesn't have a body. Everything has to be in the URL.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the API?

Comment: @Barmar Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/54892976/3783243 not valid? Documentation link would help question.

Comment: @user3783243 From the comments: **That depends on whether or not your web server is checking the body for GET requests, which I admit is not entirely standard behavior.**